# Select from a select statement using JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following sql statement :

```
select * from (select A.A_ID, (SELECT count(*) FROM X WHERE A.A_ID = X.A_ID) AS countX from A) where countX > 3 order by countX ;
```

How can I create this using JPA Criteria API ?

I know how to create the inner sql query it's just the outer one I couldn't figure out, this is how I created the inner one :

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<A_DTO> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A_DTO.class);
final Root<A> aRoot = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);

final Subquery<Long> xSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
final Root<X> xRoot = xSubquery.from(X.class);
final Expression<Long> xCount = builder.count(xRoot);
xSubquery.select(xCount);
xSubquery.where(builder.equal(xRoot.get(X_.a).get(A_.aID), aRoot.get(A_.aID)));

criteriaQuery.multiselect(aRoot.get(A_.aID), xSubquery.getSelection());

return getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

Comment: You can only select from a candidate (and joined entities) in JPQL and in Criteria, so just stop trying to do it. Reorganise your query so you are selecting a candidate

Comment: @BillyFrost I couldn't find any other solution to do that because I want to filter the result and sort it depending on countX, so the solution is to use that or the Common Table Expression which is not supported by JPA.